# Creating Custom CP Links to Other Site Channels in MSM with Zoo Flexible Admin

Tags: control-panel, multi-site-manager, profile-edit

I've got an MSM installation with 2 sites (Site 1, Site 2). I'm building out a custom control panel menu using Zoo Flexible Admin. I would like my admin to be able to click a custom link in the CP which will:

1. switch the MSM site from Site 2 to Site 1
2. take them to a specific channel edit page on Site 1

I can't seem to figure out how to combine these two into a single link, as the CP url for switching sites seems to include a query string of "C=sites" and the link to a specific channel edit page also uses the query string "C=content_edit".

The reason for the season is that Site 1 holds a Member Profile channel (using Profile:Edit). I'd like my admin (who administers both Site 1 and Site 2) to be able to quickly go to this Member Profile channel from Site 2 (avoiding the extra step of having to switch sites first, and avoiding the confusing conversation where I try to explain why the admin must go to Site 1 to change settings for a Site 2 member).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSM switcher is encoded the current pages in base64 as

```
&page=Qz1jb250ZW50X3B1Ymxpc2h8TT1lbnRyeV9mb3JtfGNoYW5uZWxfaWQ9Mw__
```

if to [decode](http://www.base64decode.org/) it, we will get

```
C=content_publish|M=entry_form|channel_id=3
```

So you can coded your pages the same way, or the most simple way -  go to a specific channel edit page on Site 1, click on MSM menu and just copy the link for current site.

**update**

no, this is not working because this function is commented in *system/expressionengine/controllers/cp/site.php  line 139 - 161*

> *"// Commenting this out for the time being, as I'm not pleased with how it's working
>      // Depending on the page you're on, you can be hit with PHP errors.  So rather than
>      // keeping this as is, we'll redirect to the CP homepage of the site switched to.
>     // We should examine this in the future to see if a better experience for the end users
>   // can be had."*

```
     if ($this->input->get_post('page') !== FALSE && 
            preg_match('/^[a-z0-9\_]+$/iD', $this->input->get_post('page')))
     {
        $parts = explode('|', base64_decode(str_replace('_', '=', $this->input->get_post('page'))));

        $page = BASE;

        foreach($parts as $part)
        {
            if ($part == '' OR ! preg_match('/^[a-z0-9\_\=]+$/iD', $part))
            {
                continue;
            }

            $page .= AMP.$part;
        }
     }
     else
     {
        $page = BASE;
     }
```

so I don't see way do this w/o uncommend this lines or write ext. which will do the same.

Comment: The problem is that when you follow the copied link from site 2, EE will switch to site 1 but it always redirects to the site 1 control panel home page instead of going to the page encoded in base64.

Comment: yes, you right, just add update into answer